# Use HTML5 local Storage to store multiple selections from a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap multiselect dropdown that looks like this:

```
<div class="dropdown" style="margin-left: 10px;">
            <select id="showops" class="ShowHide" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="1"> Show Grid      </option>
                <option value="2"> Show eMail     </option>
                <option value="3"> Show Lat/Lon   </option>
                <option value="4"> Show Last Name </option>
                <option value="5"> Show TOD       </option>
                <option value="6"> Show CREDS     </option>
                <option value="7"> Show County, St., Dist.   </option>
            </select> 
</div>
```

Each value represents a column that is hidden by default but can be shown in a MySQL/HTML table that is being edit and refreshed when a new row is added.

But after each new row is added the table refreshes and the columns that had been selected are set back to their default of hidden.

It seems to me that HTML5 Local Storage techniques might be able to preserve the selected columns between the table refreshes. I'm just not sure how to store the selected values and then to have them applied again after the refresh.

```
$('.ShowHide').change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem(this.id, this.value);
}).val(function() {
    return localStorage.getItem(this.id)
});
```

The above code only stored one item, so I think I need to store them as an array, but try as I might I'm not getting there. I'm not too good at arrays so I'm hoping someone will help me figure this out.

New Stuff: I didn't explain this very well, so lets go visual.[image: In the above] In the above screenshot the columns county, state and district are not normally shown. They were selected from the 'Show/Hide' dropdown. When a new record is dynamically added to this table (jQuery) the table refreshes without refreshing the entire page. When this happens those three columns are once again hidden. I want to prevent that.

Comment: what do you mean 'when a new row is added'? When a user selects a new option? Is this table just being made visible, or is the page refreshed, or is it handled by AJAX?

Comment: You need to use the `selectedOptions` property to get all of the values. E.g. `localStorage.setItem(this.id, Array.prototype.map.call (this.selectedOptions, o => o.value));`

Answer (score 2):

Not so complicated, just need to [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the values to/from the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```js
$('.remember-selection').each(function(r) {
    var thisSelection = $(this);
    var thisId = thisSelection.attr('id');
    var storageId = 'remember-selection-' + thisId;
    var storedInfo = localStorage.getItem(storageId);
    if( storedInfo ) {
     var rememberedOptions = storedInfo.split(',');
        thisSelection.val( rememberedOptions );
    };
    thisSelection.on('change', function(e) {
        var selectedOptions = [];
        thisSelection.find(':selected').each(function(i) {
            var thisOption = $(this);
            selectedOptions.push(thisOption.val());
        });
        localStorage.setItem(storageId, selectedOptions.join(','));
    });
});
```

```css
#showops {
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="showops" class="ShowHide remember-selection" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Show Grid</option>
    <option value="2">Show eMail</option>
    <option value="3">Show Lat/Lon</option>
    <option value="4">Show Last Name</option>
    <option value="5">Show TOD</option>
    <option value="6">Show CREDS</option>
    <option value="7">Show County, St., Dist.</option>
</select>
```

It works just fine on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nffdq27/1/).

This code would cope with many multiple selections on page, just make sure you use unique ID for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need a

```
.each(function(){ here your paste all of your code});
```

example here : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLbQaN?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

It will dynamically add and remove the selected value to localStorage and vice versa

```
<select id="showops" class="ShowHide class_of_select_box" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Sachin</option>
  <option value="2">Virat</option>
  <option value="3">Dhoni</option>
  <option value="4">Irfan</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.class_of_select_box').on('change', function(e) {
      $('.class_of_select_box').find(':selected').each(function(i) {
        var name = $(this).html();
        localStorage.setItem($(this).val(),name);
      });
      $('.remember-selection').find(':not(:selected)').each(function(i) {
        localStorage.removeItem($(this).attr('id'));
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```